# Ruby + DBI + MySQL: undefined method `to_ary' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: mysql, ruby, dbi

I am trying to connect to MySQL suing DBI. I am following [Using the Ruby DBI Module](http://www.kitebird.com/articles/ruby-dbi.html) documentation.

Here is my code:

```
require 'dbi'
begin
  dbh = DBI.connect("DBI:Mysql:<db_name>:<mysql_hostname>", "<mysql_user>", "<mysql_password>")
  row = dbh.select_one("SELECT VERSION()")
  puts "Server version: " + row[0]
rescue DBI::DatabaseError => e
  puts "Something went wrong connecting the database"
  puts e.errstr
end

sth = dbh.prepare("SHOW TABLES")
sth.execute

while row = sth.fetch
  puts row
end

sth.finish
dbh.disconnect
```

This code fails with below error:

```
Server version: 5.6.13-log
/home/user/dbi_testing.rb:14:in `puts': undefined method `to_ary' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

In above error, I am printing the MySQL version (Server version: 5.6.13-log) just to ensure that I have good working connection to the DB.

This error is thrown by the `while` loop above. So I changed it to below:

```
sth.fetch do |row|
  puts row
end
```

And still get the exact same error.

So it means either **`sth.fetch`** method does not exists or something is wrong with the way I am accessing it.

Could you help me resolving this error.

**UPDATE:** I made some progress, if I put it as below, the I can see the tables:

```
sth.fetch_hash do |row|
  puts row
end
```

The output is:

```
Server version: 5.6.13-log
{"Tables_in_mstrmd"=>"DSSCSADDRESS"}
{"Tables_in_mstrmd"=>"DSSCSBADGETB"}
{"Tables_in_mstrmd"=>"DSSCSCONTACT"}
{"Tables_in_mstrmd"=>"DSSCSDEVCKEY"}
{"Tables_in_mstrmd"=>"DSSCSPSNLZTN"}
{"Tables_in_mstrmd"=>"DSSCSRCOLCON"}
{"Tables_in_mstrmd"=>"DSSCSRINSTRG"}
{"Tables_in_mstrmd"=>"DSSCSSUBINST"}
{"Tables_in_mstrmd"=>"DSSCSSYSPROP"}
{"Tables_in_mstrmd"=>"DSSMDJRNINFO"}
{"Tables_in_mstrmd"=>"DSSMDJRNLNKS"}
{"Tables_in_mstrmd"=>"DSSMDJRNOBJC"}
{"Tables_in_mstrmd"=>"DSSMDJRNOBJD"}
{"Tables_in_mstrmd"=>"DSSMDJRNOBJS"}
{"Tables_in_mstrmd"=>"DSSMDLNKITEM"}
{"Tables_in_mstrmd"=>"DSSMDLNKPROP"}
{"Tables_in_mstrmd"=>"DSSMDOBJBLOB"}
{"Tables_in_mstrmd"=>"DSSMDOBJCMNT"}
{"Tables_in_mstrmd"=>"DSSMDOBJDEF2"}
{"Tables_in_mstrmd"=>"DSSMDOBJDEFN"}
{"Tables_in_mstrmd"=>"DSSMDOBJDEPN"}
{"Tables_in_mstrmd"=>"DSSMDOBJINFO"}
{"Tables_in_mstrmd"=>"DSSMDOBJLOCK"}
{"Tables_in_mstrmd"=>"DSSMDOBJPROP"}
{"Tables_in_mstrmd"=>"DSSMDOBJSECU"}
{"Tables_in_mstrmd"=>"DSSMDOBJTRNS"}
{"Tables_in_mstrmd"=>"DSSMDSYSPROP"}
{"Tables_in_mstrmd"=>"DSSMDUSRACCT"}
```

So, I am able to see the tables when I use **`sth.fetch_hash`**. Then what is wrong with **`sth.fetch`**?

Any pointers would be of immense help.

**UPDATE (WORKAROUND):**

I ran `puts sth.methods.sort` and here is the output:

```
fetch
fetch_all
fetch_array
fetch_hash
fetch_many
fetch_scroll
fetchable?
```

I changed **`sth.fetch`** to **`sth.fetch_array`** and now I am able to see the tables Fine.

The credit goes to a this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22657833/ruby-dbi-mysql-undefined-method-to-ary-for-nilnilclass-nomethoderror?noredirect=1#comment34513539_22657833) by [@philant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18804/philant)

So, in a way my question has got a workaround.

But I still want to know why the method **`sth.fetch`** did not work ? Any explanation would be really helpful.

Comment: Do you have a table in your DB ? Did you run `SHOW TABLES` manually ?

Comment: yep yep, I do have tables, I have verified it using mysql cli.

Comment: What are sth and row classes ? Can you print their class names ?

Comment: @philant, Could you check my update. If I use `sth.fetch_hash`, it works fine. but when I do `sth.fetch`, it fails.

Comment: @philant, thanks. Your 2nd comment got my head spinning in right direction. I got it working (not yet resolved though) by using `sth.fetch_array`.